# Is a subnet's broadcast address required to be the highest address in the subnet?

Tags: networking

For example, consider the following network:

```
IP address: 192.168.0.1
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
```

Is the broadcast address required to be 192.168.0.255?

Answer (score 2):

#### Broadcast Address Defined by RFC 919

Yes, it is required. The (direct) broadcast address is the "all-ones-address" in the local network as defined by [RFC 919](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc919#section-7), thus always the last address in a network range.

> Since the local network layer can always map an IP address into data
> link layer address, the choice of an IP "broadcast host number" is
> somewhat arbitrary.  For simplicity, it should be one not likely to
> be assigned to a real host.  The number whose bits are all ones has
> this property; [...]

#### Examples

For the network from your example, this would be 192.168.0.255, expressed in binary:

> 11000000 10101000 00000000 **11111111**

For a network like 10.0.0.32/248 (thus subnet mask 255.255.255.248), it would be 10.0.0.39 (next subnet starts at 10.0.0.40).

> 00001010 00000000 00000000 00100**111**

#### Exemptions

Exemptions exist for /31 and /32 networks. /31 networks (P2P-networks) do not have a broadcast address, they only have two hosts and are sometimes used to connect networks. /32 networks reference a single host together with dedicated routing rules (as there is no gateway).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though the broadcast address varies dependent on the subnet. From wikipedia:

> The broadcast address for an IPv4 host can be obtained by performing a
>   bitwise OR operation between the bit complement of the subnet mask and
>   the host's IP address.

Example: For broadcasting a packet to an entire IPv4 subnet using the private IP address space 172.16.0.0/12, which has the subnet mask 255.240.0.0, the broadcast address is 172.16.0.0 | 0.15.255.255 = 172.31.255.255.